# Windows batch file file download from a URL

Tags: windows, batch-file, download, scripting

I am trying to download a file from a website (ex. http://www.example.com/package.zip) using a Windows batch file.  I am getting an error code when I write the function below:

```
xcopy /E /Y "http://www.example.com/package.zip"
```

The batch file doesn't seem to like the "/" after the http.  Are there any ways to escape those characters so it doesn't assume they are function parameters?

Comment: Here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools I've tried to resume the ways of how a file can be downloaded in Windows using only native tools without third party software.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but for those who get here from now on ... Windows 10 already has native CURL.
The simplest command for this case would be like this:

curl "http://www.example.com/package.zip" --output package.zip

Answer (score 157):

With PowerShell 2.0 (Windows 7 preinstalled) you can use:

```
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://www.example.com/package.zip', 'package.zip')
```

Starting with PowerShell 3.0 (Windows 8 preinstalled) you can use [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901(v=wps.620).aspx):

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://www.example.com/package.zip -OutFile package.zip
```

From a batch file they are called:

```
powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://www.example.com/package.zip', 'package.zip')"
powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest http://www.example.com/package.zip -OutFile package.zip"
```

(PowerShell 2.0 is available for installation on XP, 3.0 for Windows 7)

Comment: Cool! Better than bitsadmin.exe, because it isn't deprecated.

Comment: @sevenforce, Does the Powershell 2.0 command also work in Powershell 3.0, or do you *have* to use that Powershell 3.0 syntax?

Comment: @RichSignell: the 2.0 command also works in 3.0.
For the 2.0 command I noticed by the way, that for a non-absolute target path the file will be saved relative to the home folder of the user.

Comment: This is amazing. I've been looking for this for so long. Thank you! Still works in 2017.

Comment: @iversen , how do you do ? can u give some code ? i want download .exe and i also used this code and not worked .. Can i download .exe using batch script?

Comment: @user7345006 I literally did the exact thing did.

Comment: @iversen but how sir ? i do in batch file. 
echo off
setlocal
cmd \k powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest https://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewer_setup -OutFile teamViewer.exe".. But got error

Comment: This works for me; `powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://albe.pw/audioshield/version.txt', '%programdata%\ChangeAudioshieldDifficulty\version.txt')"`

Comment: doesn't work it says ".DownloadFile was unexpected at this time."

Comment: The PowerShell 3.0 works perfectly on Windows 10 for me.

Comment: The 2.0 code is working for me on up-to-date Win 7. And since it also works without giving PowerShell admin permissions, let this stand as a perfect proof of concept that clicking on unknown `.bat` and `.ps1` files can really screw up your stuff.

Comment: Hi guy, if i want download a file from url and the file name is change after few day. How can i do that ? for example, today the url is http://definitions.symantec.com/defs/jdb/vd55c801.jdb but tomorrow the url is change to http://definitions.symantec.com/defs/jdb/vd55c611.jdb

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest, by default, also invokes a terminal progress bar which updates for every byte that downloads. This significantly enlarges the download time.
To avoid this, I used the suggestion from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43477248
powershell -Command "$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest http://www.example.com/package.zip -OutFile package.zip"

Comment: The last command is missing some quotations and I'd add a speed up preference:
`powershell.exe -Command "$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest 'https://...url' -OutFile 'package.zip'"`

Answer (score 110):

There's a standard Windows component which can achieve what you're trying to do: [BITS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service). It has been included in Windows since XP and 2000 SP3.

Run:

```
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "JobName" http://download.url/here.exe C:\destination\here.exe
```

The job name is simply the display name for the download job - set it to something that describes what you're doing.

Comment: Nice tool! But my win8 says: "BITSAdmin is deprecated and is not guaranteed to be available in future versions of Windows.
Administrative tools for the BITS service are now provided by BITS PowerShell cmdlets."

Comment: As I already mentioned bitsadmin is not working in automatic batches run from task scheduler :(

Comment: It's not in my XP sp2: "'bitsadmin' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: @cmroanirgo `bitsadmin` is not available in Windows XP Home Edition.

Comment: Still going strong in Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm on an infected computer with no other possible way to download a file from the web. (Even powershell was impossible to launch)

Comment: probably worth mentioning that target file name (the last argument) should be an absolute path. The relative one didn't work for me.

Comment: ON Windows 10 I got Unable to add file - 0x80070057

Comment: Got access denied error 0x80070005 running elevated command prompt

Comment: In some cases bitsadmin is preferable, if running Powershell scripts is disabled via policy.

Comment: Unable to add file - 0x80070057
Incorrect parameter. Your code gave me this.

Answer (score 29):

This might be a little off topic, but you can pretty easily download a file using **Powershell**.  Powershell comes with modern versions of Windows so you don't have to install any extra stuff on the computer.  I learned how to do it by reading this page:

http://teusje.wordpress.com/2011/02/19/download-file-with-powershell/

The code was:

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url = "http://www.example.com/file.txt"
$file = "$pwd\file.txt"
$webclient.DownloadFile($url,$file)
```

Comment: If you search that blog there are other powershell samples which make it easier with the new PowerShell version 3.0

Comment: I don't think you need `System` in `System.Net.WebClient`

Answer (score 25):

Last I checked, there isn't a command line command to connect to a URL from the MS command line. Try wget for Windows:
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

or URL2File:
http://www.chami.com/free/url2file_wincon.html

In Linux, you can use "wget".

Alternatively, you can try VBScript. They are like command line programs, but they are scripts interpreted by the wscript.exe scripts host. Here is an example of downloading a file using VBS:
https://serverfault.com/questions/29707/download-file-from-vbscript

Comment: You don't need wget or any 3rd party integration. BITS (Standard Windows Component since XP) can do it with the bitsadmin utility from the MS command line. Answer posted - albeit a little late (2 years behind?)

Answer (score 25):

### Downloading files in PURE BATCH...
**Without any JScript, VBScript, Powershell, etc... Only pure Batch!**

Some people are saying it's not possible of downloading files with a batch script without using any JScript or VBScript, etc... But they are definitely wrong!

Here is a simple method that seems to work pretty well for downloading files in your batch scripts. It should be working on almost any file's URL. It is even possible to use a proxy server if you need it.

For downloading files, we can use **BITSADMIN.EXE** from the Windows system. There is no need for downloading/installing anything or using any JScript or VBScript, etc. **Bitsadmin.exe** is present on most Windows versions, probably from XP to Windows 11.

Enjoy!

---

**USAGE:**

You can use the BITSADMIN command directly, like this:
`bitsadmin /transfer mydownloadjob /download /priority FOREGROUND "http://example.com/File.zip" "C:\Downloads\File.zip"`

Proxy Server:
For connecting using a proxy, use this command before downloading.
`bitsadmin /setproxysettings mydownloadjob OVERRIDE "proxy-server.com:8080"`

Click this [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/bitsadmin) if you want more info about BITSadmin.exe

---

**TROUBLESHOOTING:**
If you get this error: "Unable to connect to BITS - 0x80070422"
Make sure the windows service "Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS)" is enabled and try again. (It should be enabled by default.)

---

**CUSTOM FUNCTIONS**
`Call :DOWNLOAD_FILE "URL"`
`Call :DOWNLOAD_PROXY_ON "SERVER:PORT"`
`Call :DOWNLOAD_PROXY_OFF`

I made these 3 functions for simplifying the bitsadmin commands. It's easier to use and remember. It can be particularly useful if you are using it multiple times in your scripts.

PLEASE NOTE...
Before using these functions, you will first need to copy them from CUSTOM_FUNCTIONS.CMD to the end of your script. There is also a complete example: DOWNLOAD-EXAMPLE.CMD

**:DOWNLOAD_FILE "URL"**
The main function, will download files from URL.

**:DOWNLOAD_PROXY_ON "SERVER:PORT"**
(Optional) You can use this function if you need to use a proxy server.
Calling the :DOWNLOAD_PROXY_OFF function will disable the proxy server.

**EXAMPLE:**
`CALL :DOWNLOAD_PROXY_ON "proxy-server.com:8080"`
`CALL :DOWNLOAD_FILE "http://example.com/File.zip" "C:\Downloads\File.zip"`
`CALL :DOWNLOAD_PROXY_OFF`

---

**CUSTOM_FUNCTIONS.CMD**

```
:DOWNLOAD_FILE
    rem BITSADMIN COMMAND FOR DOWNLOADING FILES:
    bitsadmin /transfer mydownloadjob /download /priority FOREGROUND %1 %2
GOTO :EOF

:DOWNLOAD_PROXY_ON
    rem FUNCTION FOR USING A PROXY SERVER:
    bitsadmin /setproxysettings mydownloadjob OVERRIDE %1
GOTO :EOF

:DOWNLOAD_PROXY_OFF
    rem FUNCTION FOR STOP USING A PROXY SERVER:
    bitsadmin /setproxysettings mydownloadjob NO_PROXY
GOTO :EOF
```

---

**DOWNLOAD-EXAMPLE.CMD**

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

rem FOR DOWNLOADING FILES, THIS SCRIPT IS USING THE "BITSADMIN.EXE" SYSTEM FILE.
rem IT IS PRESENT ON MOST WINDOWS VERSION, PROBABLY FROM WINDOWS XP TO WINDOWS 10.


:SETUP

rem URL (5MB TEST FILE):
SET "FILE_URL=http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip"

rem SAVE IN CUSTOM LOCATION:
rem SET "SAVING_TO=C:\Folder\5MB.zip"

rem SAVE IN THE CURRENT DIRECTORY
SET "SAVING_TO=5MB.zip"
SET "SAVING_TO=%~dp0%SAVING_TO%"

:MAIN

ECHO.
ECHO DOWNLOAD SCRIPT EXAMPLE
ECHO.
ECHO FILE URL: "%FILE_URL%"
ECHO SAVING TO:  "%SAVING_TO%"
ECHO.

rem UNCOMENT AND MODIFY THE NEXT LINE IF YOU NEED TO USE A PROXY SERVER:
rem CALL :DOWNLOAD_PROXY_ON "PROXY-SERVER.COM:8080"
 
rem THE MAIN DOWNLOAD COMMAND:
CALL :DOWNLOAD_FILE "%FILE_URL%" "%SAVING_TO%"

rem UNCOMMENT NEXT LINE FOR DISABLING THE PROXY (IF YOU USED IT):
rem CALL :DOWNLOAD_PROXY_OFF

:RESULT
ECHO.
IF EXIST "%SAVING_TO%" ECHO YOUR FILE HAS BEEN SUCCESSFULLY DOWNLOADED.
IF NOT EXIST "%SAVING_TO%" ECHO ERROR, YOUR FILE COULDN'T BE DOWNLOADED.
ECHO.

:EXIT_SCRIPT
PAUSE
EXIT /B




rem FUNCTIONS SECTION


:DOWNLOAD_FILE
    rem BITSADMIN COMMAND FOR DOWNLOADING FILES:
    bitsadmin /transfer mydownloadjob /download /priority FOREGROUND %1 %2
GOTO :EOF

:DOWNLOAD_PROXY_ON
    rem FUNCTION FOR USING A PROXY SERVER:
    bitsadmin /setproxysettings mydownloadjob OVERRIDE %1
GOTO :EOF

:DOWNLOAD_PROXY_OFF
    rem FUNCTION FOR STOP USING A PROXY SERVER:
    bitsadmin /setproxysettings mydownloadjob NO_PROXY
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: I just updated my answer... Apparently, the download speed was insanely slow, so I changed the parameter from "/priority normal" to "/priority foreground" and it fixed the problem. It should be using now 100% of your available bandwidth. (Instead of ~ 5%)

Answer (score 11):

```
' Create an HTTP object
myURL = "http://www.google.com"
Set objHTTP = CreateObject( "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" )

' Download the specified URL
objHTTP.Open "GET", myURL, False
objHTTP.Send
intStatus = objHTTP.Status

If intStatus = 200 Then
  WScript.Echo " " & intStatus & " A OK " +myURL
Else
  WScript.Echo "OOPS" +myURL
End If
```

then

```
C:\>cscript geturl.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.7
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

200 A OK http://www.google.com
```

or just double click it to test in windows

Comment: This is only downloading into memory and not writing to a file yet. Check this answer for downloading into a file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2973344/977804

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, Windows doesn't have a built-in commandline tool to download a file. But you can do it from a VBScript, and you can generate the VBScript file from batch using echo and output redirection:

```
@echo off

rem Windows has no built-in wget or curl, so generate a VBS script to do it:
rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------
set DLOAD_SCRIPT=download.vbs
echo Option Explicit                                                    >  %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo Dim args, http, fileSystem, adoStream, url, target, status         >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo.                                                                   >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo Set args = Wscript.Arguments                                       >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")              >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo url = args(0)                                                      >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo target = args(1)                                                   >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo WScript.Echo "Getting '" ^& target ^& "' from '" ^& url ^& "'..."  >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo.                                                                   >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo http.Open "GET", url, False                                        >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo http.Send                                                          >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo status = http.Status                                               >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo.                                                                   >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo If status ^<^> 200 Then                                            >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo    WScript.Echo "FAILED to download: HTTP Status " ^& status       >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo    WScript.Quit 1                                                  >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo End If                                                             >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo.                                                                   >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")                       >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo adoStream.Open                                                     >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo adoStream.Type = 1                                                 >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo adoStream.Write http.ResponseBody                                  >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo adoStream.Position = 0                                             >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo.                                                                   >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo Set fileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")        >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo If fileSystem.FileExists(target) Then fileSystem.DeleteFile target >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo adoStream.SaveToFile target                                        >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo adoStream.Close                                                    >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
echo.                                                                   >> %DLOAD_SCRIPT%
rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------

cscript //Nologo %DLOAD_SCRIPT% http://example.com targetPathAndFile.html
```

More explanation [here](http://semitwist.com/articles/article/view/downloading-files-from-plain-batch-with-zero-dependencies)

Comment: Any reason not to do this in a separate file and simply call the VBScript file from the batch? This is going to be a terrible mess if you ever need to edit it.

Answer (score 6):

### CURL

With the build 17063 of windows 10 the CURL utility was added. To download a file you can use:

```
curl "https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip" --output pstools.zip
```

### BITSADMIN

It can be easier to use bitsadmin with a macro:

```
set "download=bitsadmin /transfer myDownloadJob /download /priority normal"
%download% "https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip" %cd%\pstools.zip
```

### Winhttp com objects

For backward compatibility you can use [winhttpjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat) (with this you can perform also POST,DELETE and the others http methods):

```
call winhhtpjs.bat "https://example.com/files/some.zip" -saveTo "c:\somezip.zip"
```

Comment: Is there a way to save the result as a variable in the bat file?

Comment: @trex005 - you can read the generated file and save the result as a variable.

Answer (score 4):

1. Download Wget from here http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gnuwin32/wget-1.11.4-1-setup.exe
2. Then install it.
3. Then make some .bat file and put this into it

   ```
   @echo off

   for /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date/t') do set y=%%k
   for /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date/t') do set d=%%k%%i%%j
   for /F "tokens=5-8 delims=:. " %%i in ('echo.^| time ^| find "current" ') do set t=%%i%%j
   set t=%t%_
   if "%t:~3,1%"=="_" set t=0%t%
   set t=%t:~0,4%
   set "theFilename=%d%%t%"
   echo %theFilename%


   cd "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin"
   wget.exe --output-document C:\backup\file_%theFilename%.zip http://someurl/file.zip
   ```
4. Adjust the URL and the file path in the script
5. Run the file and profit!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use xcopy over http. Try downloading wget for windows. That may do the trick. It is a command line utility for non-interactive download of files through http. You can get it at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Answer (score 3):

Instead of wget you can also use aria2 to download the file from a particular URL.

See the following link which will explain more about aria2:

https://aria2.github.io/

Comment: +1 for mentioning this tool that I didn't know yet. too bad it has trouble with HTTPS like wget has (have not found a way to setup a CA chain yet)

Answer (score 3):

If bitsadmin isn't your cup of tea, you can use this PowerShell command:

```
Start-BitsTransfer -Source http://www.foo.com/package.zip -Destination C:\somedir\package.zip
```

Comment: i want download .exe and i also used this code and not worked .. Can i download .exe using batch script?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Bat To Exe Converter](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php)
Create a batch file and put something like the code below into it

```
%extd% /download http://www.examplesite.com/file.zip file.zip
```

or

```
%extd% /download http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619088/windows-batch-file-file-download-from-a-url thistopic.html
```

and convert it to exe.

Answer (score 3):

There's a utility (resides with CMD) on Windows which can be run from CMD (if you have write access):

```
set url=https://www.nsa.org/content/hl-images/2017/02/09/NSA.jpg
set file=file.jpg
certutil -urlcache -split -f %url% %file%
echo Done.
```

Built in Windows application. No need for external downloads.

Tested on Win 10

Answer (score 2):

BATCH may not be able to do this, but you can use JScript or VBScript if you don't want to use tools that are not installed by default with Windows.

The first example on this page downloads a binary file in VBScript:
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_internet_download.php

This SO answer downloads a file using JScript (IMO, the better language):
[Windows Script Host (jscript): how do i download a binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164400/windows-script-host-jscript-how-do-i-download-a-binary-file/5768841#5768841)

Your batch script can then just call out to a JScript or VBScript that downloads the file.

Answer (score 2):

This should work i did the following for a game server project. It will download the zip and extract it to what ever directory you specify.

Save as **name.bat** or **name.cmd**

```
@echo off
set downloadurl=http://media.steampowered.com/installer/steamcmd.zip
set downloadpath=C:\steamcmd\steamcmd.zip
set directory=C:\steamcmd\
%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "& {Import-Module BitsTransfer;Start-BitsTransfer '%downloadurl%' '%downloadpath%';$shell = new-object -com shell.application;$zip = $shell.NameSpace('%downloadpath%');foreach($item in $zip.items()){$shell.Namespace('%directory%').copyhere($item);};remove-item '%downloadpath%';}"
echo download complete and extracted to the directory.
pause
```

Original : https://github.com/C0nw0nk/SteamCMD-AutoUpdate-Any-Gameserver/blob/master/steam.cmd

Comment: i want download .exe and i used this code and not worked .. Can i download .exe using batch script?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a scheduled task using wget, use the “Run” field in scheduled task as:

```
C:\wget\wget.exe -q -O nul "http://www.google.com/shedule.me"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this VB script:

http://www.olafrv.com/?p=385

Works like a charm.  Configured as a function with a very simple function call:

```
SaveWebBinary "http://server/file1.ext1", "C:/file2.ext2"
```

Originally from: http://www.ericphelps.com/scripting/samples/BinaryDownload/index.htm

Here is the full code for redundancy:

```
Function SaveWebBinary(strUrl, strFile) 'As Boolean
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim web, varByteArray, strData, strBuffer, lngCounter, ado
    On Error Resume Next
    'Download the file with any available object
    Err.Clear
    Set web = Nothing
    Set web = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    If web Is Nothing Then Set web = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest")
    If web Is Nothing Then Set web = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    If web Is Nothing Then Set web = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    web.Open "GET", strURL, False
    web.Send
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        SaveWebBinary = False
        Set web = Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If
    If web.Status <> "200" Then
        SaveWebBinary = False
        Set web = Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If
    varByteArray = web.ResponseBody
    Set web = Nothing
    'Now save the file with any available method
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ado = Nothing
    Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    If ado Is Nothing Then
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForWriting, True)
        strData = ""
        strBuffer = ""
        For lngCounter = 0 to UBound(varByteArray)
            ts.Write Chr(255 And Ascb(Midb(varByteArray,lngCounter + 1, 1)))
        Next
        ts.Close
    Else
        ado.Type = adTypeBinary
        ado.Open
        ado.Write varByteArray
        ado.SaveToFile strFile, adSaveCreateOverWrite
        ado.Close
    End If
    SaveWebBinary = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has very good answer in [here](https://superuser.com/a/559812/593397). My code is purely based on that answer with some modifications.

Save below snippet as **wget.bat** and put it in your system path (e.g. Put it in a directory and add this directory to system path.)

You can use it in your cli as follows:

`wget url/to/file [?custom_name]`

where `url_to_file` is compulsory and `custom_name` is optional

1. If name is not provided, then downloaded file will be saved by its own name from the url.
2. If the name is supplied, then the file will be saved by the new name.

The file url and saved filenames are displayed in ansi colored text. If that is causing problem for you, then check [this](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) github project.

```
@echo OFF
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Url=%1
set Url=!Url:http://=!
set Url=!Url:/=,!
set Url=!Url:%%20=?!
set Url=!Url: =?!

call :LOOP !Url!

set FileName=%2
if "%2"=="" set FileName=!FN!

echo.
echo.Downloading: [1;33m%1[0m to [1;33m\!FileName![0m

powershell.exe -Command wget %1 -OutFile !FileName!

goto :EOF
:LOOP
if "%1"=="" goto :EOF
set FN=%1
set FN=!FN:?= !
shift
goto :LOOP
```

*P.S. This code requires you to have PowerShell installed.*

Answer (score -6):

use ftp:

```
(ftp *yourewebsite.com*-a)
cd *directory*
get *filename.doc*
close
```

Change everything in asterisks to fit your situation.

Comment: Surely reliant on the server hosting the file to support FTP.

Comment: Questin is http related, not ftp