# SSL Certificate error on wget from Google Docs

Tags: ssl, batch-file, wget

I am writing batch script..
that will download from google docs using wget.

I am getting SSL error from google inc.

here is code wget (from this link [Windows batch file file download from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619088/windows-batch-file-file-download-from-a-url))

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date/t') do set y=%%k
for /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date/t') do set d=%%k%%i%%j
for /F "tokens=5-8 delims=:. " %%i in ('echo.^| time ^| find "current" ') do set t=%%i%%j
set t=%t%_
if "%t:~3,1%"=="_" set t=0%t%
set t=%t:~0,4%
set "theFilename=%d%%t%"
echo %theFilename%

@pause
cd "C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\TemObv\GnuWin32\bin"
wget.exe --output-document C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\TemObv\file_%theFilename%.tsv https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AqSBI1OogE84dGN2bXRSZkZPVVRuNkMtN0p4eXpyVlE&single=true&gid=0&range=A5&output=txt
@pause
```

here is ssl error from wget

```
Resolving docs.google.com... 74.125.227.72, 74.125.227.73, 74.125.227.78, ...
Connecting to docs.google.com|74.125.227.72|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify docs.google.com's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=Google In
c/CN=Google Internet Authority':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to docs.google.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
'single' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'gid' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'range' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'output' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: try creating the wget statement by itself, without the script, to first eliminate any script errors and focus on the cert errors, then post the code and results

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Windows, but the unix version of wget has a flag called no-check-certificate which can be used in this case.