# download file to directory script was ran from powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am trying to write a script or run directly from a batch from  - that will download a file from the internet and place it in a directory that the script was ran from.  I can do it already in v3 and v4 but powershell 2.0 is giving me issues.  I'm not a programmer so this is basically new to me.

What I want.

Download file from url
place file within a directory that the .bat or .ps1 was ran from

Any luck?

Comment: Describe the issues in detail and show us some code so that we can help you. What, if anything, have you tried already?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows batch file file download from a URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619088/windows-batch-file-file-download-from-a-url)

Comment: Something like this, but one that works on Powershell 2.0 powershell Start-BitsTransfer http://data-cdn.mbamupdates.com/v2/mbam/consumer/data/mbam-setup-2.0.4.1028.exe %~dp0ASE\toolsupdater\Malwarebyte.exe

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the BitsTransfer module before PowerShell can use BITS functions e.g.

```
Powershell import-module BitsTransfer; Start-BitsTransfer (source) (destination)
```

Comment: If it works, you should be able to flag this as a correct answer. Fingers crossed :)