# Powershell - Why is Using Invoke-WebRequest Much Slower Than a Browser Download?

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, powershell-3.0

I use Powershell's `Invoke-WebRequest` method to download a file from Amazon S3 to my Windows EC2 instance.

If I download the file using Chrome, I am able to download a 200 MB file in 5 seconds.  The same download in PowerShell using `Invoke-WebRequest` takes up to 5 minutes.

Why is using `Invoke-WebRequest` slower and is there a way to download at full speed in a PowerShell script?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I was using

```
Invoke-WebRequest $video_url -OutFile $local_video_url
```

I changed the above to

```
$wc = New-Object net.webclient
$wc.Downloadfile($video_url, $local_video_url)
```

This restored the download speed to what I was seeing in my browsers.

Comment: So I just ran `wc.downloadFile(ibm-s3-url, "./test.tar.gz")`, it did something, presumably download that file, _but it didnt put it in my working directory_... any idea where it might have gone?

Comment: @Groostav Mine showed up in c:\windows\system32. Not exactly the first place I'd look when downloading to a relative location.

Comment: @Groostav the current process' working directory is *not* the same thing as PowerShell's current location.

Comment: Can you show progress with this approach?

Answer (score 237):

Without switching away from `Invoke-WebRequest`, turning off the progress bar did it for me. I found the answer from this thread: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2138 (jasongin commented on Oct 3, 2016)

```
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
Invoke-WebRequest <params>
```

For my 5MB file on localhost, the download time went from 30s to 250ms.

Note that to get the progress bar back in the active shell, you need to call `$ProgressPreference = 'Continue'`.

Comment: This makes a huge difference for us too (tens of seconds down to less than a second for 10-30MB files) - I always had a suspicion that it was the progress display slowing things down but didn't know how to stop it doing it.

Comment: For a 100MB file this reduces the time from 10 Minutes to 2 Seconds. I wish developers would think more about the architecture of their software.

Comment: A lesson on how not to implement a progress bar.

Comment: For my 280MB file, it went from 33 minutes to 28 seconds. Crazy!

Comment: It appear the progress bar updates after every byte, which is utter madness.

Comment: Can't believe that `-ProgressPreference` isn't a parameter with `Invoke-WebRequest`

Comment: Updating after only every byte? I want real-time darnit, I want per bit progress bar!

Comment: Windows hasn't changed one bit.

Comment: Still a major issue in 2023.  Note, this has [additional benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75168064/3196753) as well.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this would make a difference if PowerShell is running non-interactively, but it does! I was using PowerShell to download a large file as part of a Jenkins pipeline, and this cut it down from over an hour to about 30 seconds

Comment: Good news, it's fixed in PS 7.  Which apparently isn't the one they distribute yet with windows 11? LOL https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16914#issuecomment-1050290763

Answer (score 29):

`$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'`
I got this down from 52min down to 14sec, for a file of 450 M.
Spectacular.

Comment: please include more information in your answer, eg where does the setting you describe get set/defined?

Comment: This is a built-in [preference variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-5.1#progresspreference) to PowerShell, and controls whether or not a progress bar is displayed for certain operations, such as downloading files via `Invoke-WebRequest`. The reason this improves performance here is because `Invoke-WebRequest` (and `Invoke-RestMethod`) count the downloaded bytes too often (*every single byte* I believe), so the cmdlet is actually slowed down as it tallies how many bytes have been processed.

Answer (score 20):

One-liner to download a file to the temp directory:

```
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("https://www.google.com", "$env:temp\index.html")
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Lloyd asked: "is there a way to download at full speed in a PowerShell script?"  This answer is a one-liner way to do that.  Downloading to the temp directory is the canonical way to demonstrate this.

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest`, which the OP is already using, does internally the same what `WebClient.DownloadFile`.

Comment: This is actually a good answer, WebClient.DownloadFile is much faster than Invoke-WebRequest due to the way Invoke-WebRequest tracks its own progress

Comment: Absolutely relevant, this fixes exactly the problem OP has (and mine :) )

Comment: I actually prefer this one, because you don't have to worry about clobbering `$ProgressPreference` or saving/restoring it. As long as you're simply downloading a file, I prefer the one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

I just hit this issue today, if you change the ContentType argument to *application/octet-stream* it is much faster (as fast as using webclient). The reason is because the Invoke-Request command will not try and parse the response as JSON or XML.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType "application/octet-stream" -Uri $video_url  -OutFile $local_video_url
```

Comment: `-ContentType` is for `POST` requests only AFAIK so it probably won't make a difference.

Comment: You'd be better off using the `-UseBasicParsing` parameter but that won't make much of a difference for static files. Setting `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` before calling `Invoke-WebRequest` ***greatly*** improves the performance.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the progress bar of `Invoke-WebRequest` is slowing file download *a lot* on Windows Powershell 5.1 (the version included in Windows OS). It's much faster on later Powershell versions (I tested it on Powershell 7.3).

IMO, if you are forced to use Windows Powershell then the best way is to use curl since it's [included on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2017/20171219-tar-and-curl-come-to-windows) by default now. Just be aware that by default Windows Powershell has alias named `curl` for `Invoke-WebRequest` so to run `curl` program you need to write `curl.exe` to tell Windows Powershell that you don't want to use `curl` alias.

This command takes 11 minutes on Windows Powershell 5.1 and 23 seconds on Powershell 7.3:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Verbose -Uri "https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/7c048383-52b1-47cb-91d1-acfaf1a3fcc9/ea510c0bfa44f33cc3ddea79090a51e1/dotnet-sdk-6.0.410-win-x64.exe" -OutFile ".\dotnet-sdk-6.0.410-win-x64.exe"
```

and this takes 15 seconds:

```
curl.exe -fSLo .\dotnet-sdk-6.0.410-win-x64.exe https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/7c048383-52b1-47cb-91d1-acfaf1a3fcc9/ea510c0bfa44f33cc3ddea79090a51e1/dotnet-sdk-6.0.410-win-x64.exe
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, I replace Invoke-WebRequest by CURL.exe call using Invoke-Expression and a command line in my script

went from 10 min to 40 sec of download

Comment: This does not answer why one method is faster than the other