# Invoke-WebRequest status blocks password prompt

Tags: linux, macos, powershell

I have an installer that calls `Invoke-WebRequest` and then shortly after calls `sudo <command>`, but the line is all filled up with output from the WebRequest.

From Terminal:

```bash
pwsh
```

Then, from PowerShell:

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://google.com -OutFile /dev/null; sudo ls -al
```

[image]

How do I make sure the password prompt is visible on its own line?  I prefer to not call `Clear-Host`, since I would like to retain output from previous commands on the screen for the user to read.

This issue is present on PowerShell for macOS and Linux, but not for Windows, since Windows' own PowerShell tends to show the progress indicator at the top of the window.

Comment: What about outputting a couple blank lines (e.g `Write-Host "`n"`) after the `Invoke-WebRequest` command?

Comment: Did you try?  When I did earlier, the terminal was still plagued by the case of the lingering download indicator.

Comment: The return is being truncated because you are using -Outfile /dev/Null.  To solve issue you would need to filter the Outfile and remove everything except the return.

Comment: @jdweng I do not understand your statement.  `Invoke-WebRequest` has support for `-OutFile` and that's what I'm using.   `/dev/null` is an example only.  The issue is reproducible with a real outfile as well.

Comment: Not sure.  The password would normally would send the return  back to the terminal.  I suspect the -Outfile somehow is suppressing the return.  It is worth a try and see what happens.

Comment: What is worth a try?   Please be specific as possible.

Answer (score 1):

A viable workaround is to [suppress the indicator completely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43477248/3196753), which also has a major speed advantage over the default behavior.

```
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' # <---- ADD THIS LINE
Invoke-WebRequest https://google.com -OutFile /dev/null; sudo ls -al
```

Comment: @rogerdpack I had to click my own link to understand what I meant.  Yes, speed, edited. :)