# powershell's Invoke-WebRequest takes 10X times more time to download a file than using a web browser

Tags: powershell, download, httpwebrequest, invoke-webrequest, timedelay

The issue i m reporting here can be replicated on any system having powershell.

Downloading https://cdn.studios.com/Archive/23.X/23.3.0/fulEngine-23.3.0.32.zip through browser takes less than a minute [30 seconds] whereas downloading the same file using `Invoke-WebRequest` takes more than 5 minutes.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://cdn.studios.com/Archive/23.X/23.3.0/fulEngine-23.3.0.32.zip -OutFile C:\Users\HOME\Downloads\fulEngine-23.3.0.32.zip
```

[image]

Can we reduce the time it takes to download the file `Invoke-WebRequest` and get it close to the time the web-browser takes to download?

Explanation of why so much time difference will also be appreciated.

Alternate tools using PowerShell or workarounds are also appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Powershell - Why is Using Invoke-WebRequest Much Slower Than a Browser Download?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43477248/1701026)?