# Batch file to download files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, download, scripting

I have a batch file, and I'd like to make a part of it save/download a file from a website...

eg.
example.com/file.jpg

This would then be saved to a location on my computer. Is there a way to do this? I've tried using the `copy`/`xcopy`/`ROBOCOPY` commands, but to no avail.

My operating system is Windows 8.1

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`bitsadmin /?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619088/windows-batch-file-file-download-from-a-url) it's native in windows [but not sure in windows8](http://ss64.com/nt/bitsadmin.html)

```
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "JobName" http://download.url/here.exe C:\destination\here.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

It is operating system specific. On POSIX systems, you might use [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/) or [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to download files; perhaps they exist on your OS (even if it not POSIX compliant, e.g. Windows, to which both utilities have been ported)

Both `curl` & `wget` are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). You can download their source code, perhaps adapt it to your additional needs (I guess you won't have to do that, but who knows?), compile them into some executable, and run that executable on the command line.

Comment: I updated my question to include OS - Windows 8.1. Curl sounds like what I need... Is it just an executable, called from the command line/batch file, acting the same as a normal windows command?

Comment: It is a free software that you can compile into an executable.